# Java Frames graphics with parameters

Tags: java, swing

I adjusted the parameters on my Frame class to take (int []x,String[]y,String z) but i still get an error when I run the program. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

I keep getting the error that **the constructor is undefined**

This is in the main runner (yes, totcat is an int[], names is a String[], and category is a String):

```
Frame f=new Frame(totcat,names,category);
```

This is the frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    int []z;
    String []x;
    String y;

    public Frame(int[]z,String[]x,String y)
    {
        super();
        this.z=z;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();

        Panel p=new Panel(z,x,y);
        Insets frameInsets=getInsets();

        int frameWidth=p.getWidth()+(frameInsets.left+frameInsets.right);
        int frameHeight=p.getHeight()+(frameInsets.top+frameInsets.bottom);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth,frameHeight));

        setLayout(null);
        add(p);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the error you are getting so people can help .

Comment: Please format your code with better indentation. Also what error do you get? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error? What line causes the error?

Comment: Probably a name collision between your `Frame` class and `java.awt.Frame`, since you're importing `java.awt.*`.

Comment: David has a valid point.  awt.Frame is in the path since you imported awt.*.  Name you Frame class something non-colliding like MyFrame.